# Why First element of a csv file content has a red star symbol?

Tags: arrays, csv

I read a csv file using laravel. This is very straightforward task as follows:

```
 $file = Input::file('bulk_order');

$filename = time().'-'.rand(2000,99999999).'-'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
$result = $file->move('bulkOrder',$filename);
$uploadedFilePath = 'bulkOrder/'.$filename;
$contents = $this->csvToArray($uploadedFilePath);
unlink($uploadedFilePath);
$keys = array();
if(count($contents)){
    $keys = array_keys($contents[0]);
}
$filteredKeys = array();
foreach($keys as $key){
    $key = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]+;/i","",$key); 
    $key = trim($key);
    array_push($filteredKeys, $key);
}
print_r($filteredKeys);

$fields = array('care_of','customer_mobile','customer_name','customer_district','customer_upazila','customer_address','product_weight_kg','delivery_time','cash_collection');
$diff = array_diff($filteredKeys,$fields);
print_r($diff);
exit;
```

But I get a red star symbol at the very beginning element as follows:

[image]

Here there is a red start at the beginning of 'care_of'. To be sure I just compare this array with $fields array and here you can see the difference is 'care_of' with red star. This is a very strange problem I found ever. It kills my 8 hours, I tried all possible ways but no luck. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The file/array appears to have been encoded using UTF-16 but is being interpreted as UTF-8. Each of the red dots represents a null byte which is supposed to be part of a two-byte character in UTF-16 but is its own character in UTF-8.

Please check for invisible/null bytes.

Comment: invisible/null bytes is: \ufeff